# R dplyr filter string condition on multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df such as

```
df <-read.table(text="
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  A  B  X  C
2  A  B  C  X
3  A  C  C  C
4  B  D  V  A
5  B  Z  Z  D", header=T)
```

How can I filter variables v2 to v5 if they have an "X". I've seen some examples using filter at but those seem to work only for numeric conditions.

```
filter_at(vars(contains("prefix")), all_vars(.>5))
```

and replacing >5 for "X" does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter_at` with `any_vars` to select rows that have at least one value of `"X"`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(vars(v2:v5), any_vars(. == 'X'))

#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  1  A  B  X  C
#2  2  A  B  C  X
```

However, `filter_at` has been superseeded so to translate this into `across` you can do :

```
df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(v2:v5, ~. == 'X')))
```

---

It is also easier in base R :

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] == 'X') > 0, ]
```

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr` 1.0.4, we can use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(if_any(v2:v5, ~ . == 'X'))
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  1  A  B  X  C
#2  2  A  B  C  X
```