# Check multiple columns if any of them is a particular value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to check multiple columns for a specific string and return a value if at least one of them matches.

For example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    result = case_when(
      col1 == "string" |
      col2 == "string" | 
      col3 == "string" | 
      col4 == "string" | 
      col5 == "string" ~ as.integer(1),
      T ~ as.integer(2)
    )
  )
```

Is there a way to do this in such a way that it checks for at least one NA in each of those columns and assigns the value to the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413115/6851825

Answer (score 1):

You may check each rows by `dplyr::across`

For example data `df` defined like

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("string","a","a","a","a", NA),
  col2 = c("b","b","string","b","b","b"),
  col3 = c("c","c","c","c","c","c"),
  col4 = c("d","d","d","d","d","d")
)
    col1   col2 col3 col4
1 string      b    c    d
2      a      b    c    d
3      a string    c    d
4      a      b    c    d
5      a      b    c    d
6   <NA>      b    c    d
```

You may try

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(rowSums(across(col1:col4, ~ .x == "string"), na.rm = T)>0, 1, 2),
         res2 = rowSums(across(col1:col4, ~ is.na(.x)))>0)
```

In `res`, if any of column have `"string"`, `rowSums(...)` will have positive value, then assign 1 and if not, assign 2.

In the same way, `res2` will check if there exist `NA`.

Note that they are row-wise operated.

Result is like

```
  col1   col2   col3  col4    res res2 
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
1 string b      c     d         1 FALSE
2 a      b      c     d         2 FALSE
3 a      string c     d         1 FALSE
4 a      b      c     d         2 FALSE
5 a      b      c     d         2 FALSE
6 NA     b      c     d         2 TRUE
```

If there any problems or questions, please let me know.